# How do I understand which doctoral school in a university I should apply to when my research topic is relevant to multiple of them?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, interdisciplinary

Suppose a university has three doctoral schools:

1. Doctoral School of Exact & Natural Sciences
2. Interdisciplinary doctoral school

Say, I have a research topic that relates to both computer science and biology. Then, logically, my research topic can be relevant to any of the above doctoral schools.

How do I understand which doctoral school I should apply to for the best chance of acceptance?

Comment: I'm very confused. You say you have found your advisor already. In this case, wouldn't you apply to the department where your advisor works? Or the one he tells you to apply to? Second, what part of the world are you in? Normally one gets a PhD in a _subject_ like chemistry or CS; "doctoral school for natural science" is not really a thing (at least in my part of the world).

Comment: @cag51, sorry for the mistake. The Doctoral School of CS&Math has been merged to the Doctoral School of Exact & Natural Sciences in 2020.

Comment: There are good answers below, please accept one. The point is quite simple: the school is typically not chosen by you, but by your supervisor. Suppervisors are attached to schools. If your supervisor is attached to multiple schools, discuss with him. If he is not associated with any school, reach out also to other supervisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give enough information here to make a choice and you will have to gather more. In fact it might by any of them, or none.

You will need to find an advisor who is interested enough in what you want to do to take you on. They could be in any of the there schools. You need to look at the faculty and what they actually do. Only then can you make a choice.

Alternatively you will need to drop your proposed project for now and do something else for a degree before you take it up again. But knowing what the faculty does in those three schools will, again, give you information that can keep you close enough that you learn the appropriate research process to combine CS and biology.

The advisor is key for almost everyone. It is hard to be successful in grad school without a supportive advisor. Some do it, but it is much harder.

Comment: I have found my advisor already. He is from chemistry and works on protein, but I don't have any chemical background.

Comment: You need to work it out with him. I wonder if there is enough overlap of interest to make this a fruitful pairing. You probably don't want a chem degree, in any case. He might advise you on schools, depending on his own associations.

Comment: Talk to your adviser about which journals / conferences they expect you to publish in. That may have a factor in the decision. For example my advisor strongly believes that by doing a PhD in the Department of Computing means I must publish my research in reputable computer science journals, not engineering journals despite my topic overlap. Note: other faculty disagree, I've also been told that a PhD is faculty agnostic and I can publish where I want - but going against your advisors advice is probably not the best option.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth www.mdpi.com/journal/biomolecules